# a href is not working on email subject

Tags: php, html, email

Hi i am using the following code to send an email from php, here send mail is working fine but href in mail body is not working, below is my code,

```
$subject="Form";
$to="ashok@gmail.com";
$cc="test@gmail.com";
$msg="Hi";          
$msg.="<a href='www.google.com' target='_blank'>Click here</a>";
$msg.="<br><br>Regards,<br>Ashok;

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:'.$from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$cc. "\r\n";

 mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

Please figureout the issue

Comment: Do you see code highlight?

Comment: You forgot a `"` and the end of the `$msg` string. Maybe setting `display_errors` to `on` in your dev env and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` in your script will tell you what went wrong during execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give the complete URL of any link with `http://` or `https://` in the email text. I had expericed this issue with gmail client, that makes the url blank if you missed the `http://` or `https://`

```
$msg.="<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Click here</a>";
```

This should work.

Comment: yeah i forget to add `http://`